# VIFs in Fixed-Effects-model

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

I know that R is providing some Warnings messages when you try to get your VIFs to test for multicollinearity.

But why is that?

Does someone know a good paper or the answer itself?

**CODE:**

```
FORMULAR.PLM.BASELINE <- StockPrice ~ EPS + BookValuePS + AssetsTotal.LOG + LeverageRatio + AvgAnnualDividendyield + Dummy.ESG + Dummy.Sektor
MOD.FE.TIME.VIF <- plm(FORMULAR.PLM.BASELINE, data = PD.Datensatz_final_so, model = "within", effect = "time")
vif(MOD.FE.TIME.VIF)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
> Error in R[subs, subs] : subscript out of bounds In addition: Warning
> message: In vif.default(MOD.FE.TIME.VIF) : No intercept: vifs may not
> be sensible.
```

**DATA:**

```
structure(list(Company = c("AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC", "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC", 
"AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC", "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC", 
"AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC", "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC", 
"AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC", "HESS CORP", "HESS CORP", "HESS CORP", 
"HESS CORP", "HESS CORP", "HESS CORP", "HESS CORP", "APACHE CORP", 
"APACHE CORP", "APACHE CORP", "APACHE CORP", "APACHE CORP", "APACHE CORP", 
"APACHE CORP", "AVERY DENNISON CORP", "AVERY DENNISON CORP", 
"AVERY DENNISON CORP", "AVERY DENNISON CORP", "AVERY DENNISON CORP", 
"AVERY DENNISON CORP", "AVERY DENNISON CORP", "BALL CORP", "BALL CORP", 
"BALL CORP", "BALL CORP", "BALL CORP", "BALL CORP", "BALL CORP", 
"CHEVRON CORP", "CHEVRON CORP", "CHEVRON CORP", "CHEVRON CORP", 
"CHEVRON CORP", "CHEVRON CORP", "CHEVRON CORP", "ECOLAB INC", 
"ECOLAB INC", "ECOLAB INC", "ECOLAB INC", "ECOLAB INC", "ECOLAB INC", 
"ECOLAB INC", "EXXON MOBIL CORP", "EXXON MOBIL CORP", "EXXON MOBIL CORP", 
"EXXON MOBIL CORP", "EXXON MOBIL CORP", "EXXON MOBIL CORP", "EXXON MOBIL CORP", 
"FMC CORP", "FMC CORP", "FMC CORP", "FMC CORP", "FMC CORP", "FMC CORP", 
"FMC CORP", "HALLIBURTON CO", "HALLIBURTON CO", "HALLIBURTON CO", 
"HALLIBURTON CO", "HALLIBURTON CO", "HALLIBURTON CO", "HALLIBURTON CO", 
"HELMERICH & PAYNE", "HELMERICH & PAYNE", "HELMERICH & PAYNE", 
"HELMERICH & PAYNE", "HELMERICH & PAYNE", "HELMERICH & PAYNE", 
"HELMERICH & PAYNE", "HOLLYFRONTIER CORP", "HOLLYFRONTIER CORP", 
"HOLLYFRONTIER CORP", "HOLLYFRONTIER CORP", "HOLLYFRONTIER CORP", 
"HOLLYFRONTIER CORP", "HOLLYFRONTIER CORP", "INTL FLAVORS & FRAGRANCES", 
"INTL FLAVORS & FRAGRANCES", "INTL FLAVORS & FRAGRANCES", "INTL FLAVORS & FRAGRANCES", 
"INTL FLAVORS & FRAGRANCES", "INTL FLAVORS & FRAGRANCES", "INTL FLAVORS & FRAGRANCES", 
"INTL PAPER CO", "INTL PAPER CO", "INTL PAPER CO", "INTL PAPER CO", 
"INTL PAPER CO", "INTL PAPER CO", "INTL PAPER CO", "MARATHON OIL CORP", 
"MARATHON OIL CORP", "MARATHON OIL CORP", "MARATHON OIL CORP", 
"MARATHON OIL CORP", "MARATHON OIL CORP", "MARATHON OIL CORP", 
"NEWMONT CORP", "NEWMONT CORP", "NEWMONT CORP", "NEWMONT CORP", 
"NEWMONT CORP", "NEWMONT CORP", "NEWMONT CORP", "NUCOR CORP", 
"NUCOR CORP", "NUCOR CORP", "NUCOR CORP", "NUCOR CORP", "NUCOR CORP", 
"NUCOR CORP", "OCCIDENTAL PETROLEUM CORP", "OCCIDENTAL PETROLEUM CORP", 
"OCCIDENTAL PETROLEUM CORP", "OCCIDENTAL PETROLEUM CORP", "OCCIDENTAL PETROLEUM CORP", 
"OCCIDENTAL PETROLEUM CORP", "OCCIDENTAL PETROLEUM CORP", "ONEOK INC", 
"ONEOK INC", "ONEOK INC", "ONEOK INC", "ONEOK INC", "ONEOK INC", 
"ONEOK INC", "PPG INDUSTRIES INC", "PPG INDUSTRIES INC", "PPG INDUSTRIES INC", 
"PPG INDUSTRIES INC", "PPG INDUSTRIES INC", "PPG INDUSTRIES INC", 
"PPG INDUSTRIES INC"), Year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"), class = "factor"), ggroup = c(1510, 
1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 
1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1510, 1510, 
1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 
1510, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1510, 1510, 1510, 
1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 
1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 
1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 
1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 
1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1010, 1010, 
1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 
1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1010, 1010, 1010, 
1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 1010, 
1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510, 1510), gvkey = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), .Label = c("1209", 
"1380", "1678", "1913", "1988", "2991", "4213", "4503", "4510", 
"5439", "5581", "5667", "6078", "6104", "7017", "7881", "8030", 
"8068", "8151", "8247"), class = "factor"), StockPrice = c(85.19, 
84.02, 111.78, 144.23, 130.11, 143.82, 164.08, 56.8, 52.96, 83, 
73.82, 48.48, 62.29, 47.47, 90.58, 78.5, 85.94, 62.67, 44.47, 
63.47, 42.22, 28.68, 34.92, 50.19, 51.88, 62.66, 70.22, 114.86, 
17.86, 22.38, 25.83, 34.09, 36.37, 37.54, 37.85, 106.4, 108.14, 
124.91, 112.18, 89.96, 117.7, 125.19, 57.81, 71.9, 104.27, 104.52, 
114.38, 117.22, 134.18, 84.76, 86.55, 101.2, 92.45, 77.95, 90.26, 
83.64, 43.02, 58.52, 75.46, 57.03, 39.13, 56.56, 94.66, 34.51, 
34.69, 50.75, 39.33, 34.04, 54.09, 48.87, 58.36, 56.01, 84.08, 
67.42, 53.55, 77.4, 64.64, 23.4, 46.55, 49.69, 37.48, 39.89, 
32.76, 51.22, 52.42, 66.54, 85.98, 101.36, 119.64, 117.83, 152.61, 
29.6, 39.84, 49.03, 53.58, 37.7, 53.06, 57.94, 29.27, 30.66, 
35.3, 28.29, 12.59, 17.31, 16.93, 60.01, 46.44, 23.03, 18.9, 
17.99, 34.07, 37.52, 39.57, 43.16, 53.38, 49.05, 40.3, 59.52, 
63.58, 93.7, 76.61, 95.1, 80.61, 67.61, 71.23, 73.66, 43.35, 
42.75, 62.18, 49.79, 24.66, 57.41, 53.45, 41.75, 67.68, 94.83, 
115.58, 98.82, 94.76, 116.82), EPS = c(5.75, 5.53, 4.74, 4.66, 
5.95, 2.92, 13.76, 5.01, 5.93, 15.53, 8.11, -10.68, -19.37, -12.93, 
11.94, 5.14, 5.65, -14.07, -61.16, -3.71, 3.42, 1.78, 1.65, 2.49, 
2.69, 3.01, 3.63, 3.2, 1.34, 1.3, 1.39, 1.7, 1.02, 0.83, 1.07, 
13.54, 13.42, 11.18, 10.21, 2.46, -0.27, 4.88, 1.95, 2.41, 3.23, 
4.01, 3.38, 4.2, 5.21, 8.43, 9.7, 7.37, 7.6, 3.85, 1.88, 4.63, 
2.58, 3.02, 2.17, 2.31, 3.66, 1.56, 3.99, 3.09, 2.85, 2.37, 4.13, 
-0.79, -6.69, -0.53, 4.07, 5.44, 6.93, 3.57, 3.92, -0.53, -1.18, 
6.46, 8.41, 3.67, 1.43, 3.92, -1.48, 4.57, 3.32, 3.13, 4.35, 
5.12, 5.21, 5.09, 3.74, 3.1, 1.82, 3.15, 1.3, 2.25, 2.2, 5.19, 
4.15, 2.24, 2.49, 4.48, -3.26, -2.53, -6.73, 0.74, 3.65, -4.94, 
1.02, 0.43, -1.18, -0.18, 2.45, 1.59, 1.53, 2.23, 1.12, 2.49, 
4.12, 8.34, 5.68, 7.34, 0.79, -10.23, -0.75, 1.71, 1.72, 1.75, 
1.29, 1.5, 1.17, 1.67, 1.3, 3.58, 3.07, 11.27, 7.6, 5.18, 3.3, 
6.21), BookValuePS = c(27.21, 30.67, 33.58, 34.63, 33.73, 32.72, 
46.27, 54.46, 61.75, 75.99, 77.68, 67.77, 45.92, 35.08, 75.5, 
80.54, 84.55, 67.54, 6.79, 16.46, 19.46, 15.53, 12.13, 17.21, 
11.53, 10.61, 10.48, 11.88, 3.69, 3.6, 4.11, 3.73, 4.56, 10.85, 
11.25, 61.1, 70, 77.78, 82.3, 81.76, 77.72, 78.67, 23.92, 20.78, 
24.49, 24.38, 23.31, 23.59, 26.31, 31.7, 35.84, 39.36, 40.76, 
40.72, 40.12, 44.1, 8.74, 10.75, 11.24, 11.48, 13.95, 14.62, 
19.97, 14.38, 17.02, 15.12, 19.18, 18.13, 10.93, 9.57, 30.66, 
35.9, 41.81, 45.37, 45.45, 42.23, 38.38, 32.84, 29.49, 29.94, 
28, 27.84, 6.58, 30.49, 13.73, 15.4, 17.99, 18.76, 19.77, 20.42, 
21.3, 15.32, 14.45, 18.3, 11.89, 9.32, 10.65, 15.79, 24.16, 25.9, 
27.44, 30.91, 27.4, 20.71, 13.77, 26.11, 27.77, 20.35, 20.63, 
22.18, 20.18, 19.9, 23.58, 24.02, 23.96, 24.3, 23.14, 24.66, 
27.31, 46.32, 49.45, 53.63, 44.76, 31.81, 28.14, 26.89, 10.69, 
10.33, 11.35, 2.83, 1.6, 0.89, 18.58, 10.33, 13.24, 17.2, 18.73, 
18.36, 18.17, 21.7), ESGscore = c(84.2750015258789, 81.9225006103516, 
77.4024963378906, 80.1125030517578, 78.6449966430664, 76.3775024414062, 
79.2699966430664, 69.4899978637695, 65.8300018310547, 64.4300003051758, 
74.3000030517578, 75.7600021362305, 71.4599990844727, 74.6900024414062, 
55.8300018310547, 56.0900001525879, 57.5, 60.75, 60.8800010681152, 
67.379997253418, 71.9899978637695, 82.9000015258789, 77.3899993896484, 
76.9300003051758, 78.7399978637695, 76.2283325195312, 74.2125015258789, 
68.3600006103516, 64.4100036621094, 65.6600036621094, 63.75, 
67.7300033569336, 67.5699996948242, 74.4300003051758, 68.5699996948242, 
86.5100021362305, 84.3099975585938, 82.6600036621094, 82.3399963378906, 
88.4100036621094, 90.0800018310547, 92.25, 74.6999969482422, 
72.3600006103516, 68.3899993896484, 67.9300003051758, 65.629997253418, 
74.9000015258789, 74.8600006103516, 81.6999969482422, 79.370002746582, 
79.0899963378906, 75.25, 81.9499969482422, 81.0199966430664, 
88.3399963378906, 59.8199996948242, 55.6500015258789, 52.2999992370605, 
51.8499984741211, 56.9199981689453, 66.620002746582, 65.3300018310547, 
85.9800033569336, 83.9499969482422, 85.1100006103516, 67.4300003051758, 
76.4400024414062, 69.9199981689453, 78.4599990844727, 19.0599994659424, 
17.5200004577637, 18.1200008392334, 23.5025005340576, 35.5349998474121, 
36.7350006103516, 41.1725006103516, 27.8700008392334, 33.7700004577637, 
37.6699981689453, 47.7599983215332, 50.2400016784668, 55.25, 
58.3800010681152, 70.7600021362305, 71.9800033569336, 75.1500015258789, 
75.1399993896484, 79.4100036621094, 70.1500015258789, 76.5299987792969, 
71.3399963378906, 80.1900024414062, 72.9899978637695, 66.9400024414062, 
73.8000030517578, 76.2399978637695, 72.0500030517578, 80.4700012207031, 
80.5100021362305, 79.6800003051758, 76.4300003051758, 78.6399993896484, 
77.2300033569336, 76.5899963378906, 81.6399993896484, 77.8600006103516, 
79.5100021362305, 85.9800033569336, 81.120002746582, 78.75, 80.7099990844727, 
59.8600006103516, 52.3400001525879, 54.9300003051758, 54.8899993896484, 
64.120002746582, 62.4900016784668, 61.7200012207031, 77.5899963378906, 
79.5999984741211, 79.0899963378906, 72.6999969482422, 76, 72.5199966430664, 
78.5100021362305, 62.1800003051758, 62.060001373291, 65.1699981689453, 
65.0800018310547, 67.8499984741211, 66.75, 66.5299987792969, 
66.8099975585938, 66.2099990844727, 70.7600021362305, 73.4100036621094, 
74.2900009155273, 70.0299987792969, 71.4300003051758), LeverageRatio = c(0.594435561205841, 
0.617679355403529, 0.605486789891209, 0.585704565106127, 0.584301032659383, 
0.607893538666041, 0.453831624609765, 0.526880621422731, 0.514513938445248, 
0.421808485755719, 0.424412877806003, 0.433075010966516, 0.492225987910974, 
0.521893388715819, 0.466561641467023, 0.50435484136523, 0.458182585135552, 
0.536441950243066, 0.863814881647384, 0.722989475553977, 0.661709698020254, 
0.666478988304306, 0.690341393278699, 0.676354504930841, 0.755401139345263, 
0.766383635343921, 0.789486848203547, 0.796336317416944, 0.832646959442815, 
0.85152722608109, 0.846556170952766, 0.863545109551454, 0.872015950820485, 
0.787608977926173, 0.77045838429728, 0.420539064513973, 0.414014816595273, 
0.412369508931914, 0.417244930946599, 0.426101922939614, 0.440337129630342, 
0.416388895455584, 0.689339285962852, 0.654171637758199, 0.625987329478904, 
0.624183852632949, 0.629331005652438, 0.623511997043816, 0.618357519590785, 
0.53362009593659, 0.503099207597478, 0.498272819542802, 0.50099429745374, 
0.492778196806015, 0.493436548254086, 0.461735462056663, 0.668598911289985, 
0.661560602236253, 0.709695906149125, 0.713416346784009, 0.705069637526097, 
0.681119995202526, 0.70869946604795, 0.442581408117582, 0.424844947099599, 
0.535263319987681, 0.495440446650124, 0.581452005847003, 0.651518518518518, 
0.668247956946382, 0.346499145342847, 0.329672942621959, 0.290686407542856, 
0.272377520553529, 0.315234369479579, 0.33241919028586, 0.353323181006733, 
0.495472522128971, 0.413984333584541, 0.403422922342673, 0.401603334682229, 
0.373721043240805, 0.503861576091451, 0.497685035920943, 0.627590017963253, 
0.615704103314394, 0.560867296803568, 0.565457600575885, 0.572662204137801, 
0.595157943268954, 0.633783603720298, 0.754751231800837, 0.803937424190589, 
0.74292692210099, 0.821677590294241, 0.873017948801779, 0.869815564552407, 
0.807627643571365, 0.453253004367091, 0.482156007477483, 0.456934306569343, 
0.416289467107273, 0.425799263408746, 0.435871872386956, 0.468108304561148, 
0.530610759263303, 0.535480607082631, 0.590494265869811, 0.58765451918446, 
0.549281232626479, 0.490228709999525, 0.484073335602782, 0.486979724850567, 
0.460038216337232, 0.497097505794197, 0.502272882334361, 0.479531926496852, 
0.482388666486795, 0.448336979534749, 0.373459463060422, 0.376794891761408, 
0.378972682631799, 0.378606089692316, 0.439418007689297, 0.501333828202927, 
0.51049350402132, 0.836560364180467, 0.865684522390699, 0.867974398512285, 
0.961311203532902, 0.978260029529959, 0.988304857334294, 0.671857550967407, 
0.774092615769712, 0.744111349036403, 0.689087814410893, 0.705397258715805, 
0.70818692902319, 0.693956496924345, 0.663985971701536), AvgAnnualDividendyield = c(0.0266, 
0.0314, 0.0298, 0.0253, 0.0241, 0.025, 0.0245, 0.006, 0.009, 
0.01, 0.012, 0.016, 0.021, 0.025, 0.007, 0.01, 0.011, 0.011, 
0.018, 0.019, 0.019, 0.029, 0.028, 0.03, 0.023, 0.02, 0.023, 
0.019, 0.008, 0.01, 0.011, 0.009, 0.008, 0.007, 0.009, 0.031, 
0.033, 0.033, 0.035, 0.045, 0.043, 0.039, 0.013, 0.016, 0.008, 
0.011, 0.012, 0.013, 0.012, 0.023, 0.025, 0.027, 0.028, 0.035, 
0.037, 0.041, 0.011, 0.008, 0.01, 0.01, 0.015, 0.017, 0.01, 0.008, 
0.011, 0.011, 0.011, 0.018, 0.017, 0.015, 0.0043, 0.0055, 0.0131, 
0.0254, 0.0443, 0.0447, 0.0481, 0.054, 0.09, 0.068, 0.071, 0.03, 
0.045, 0.042, 0.019, 0.027, 0.014, 0.017, 0.017, 0.019, 0.019, 
0.037, 0.035, 0.029, 0.032, 0.036, 0.044, 0.036, 0.028, 0.023, 
0.021, 0.023, 0.03, 0.014, 0.014, 0.021, 0.027, 0.037, 0.01, 
0.005, 0.004, 0.007, 0.036, 0.036, 0.031, 0.029, 0.034, 0.031, 
0.026, 0.019, 0.031, 0.023, 0.031, 0.04, 0.042, 0.048, 0.036, 
0.033, 0.034, 0.035, 0.062, 0.06, 0.052, 0.027, 0.022, 0.015, 
0.013, 0.013, 0.015, 0.016), AssetsTotal.LOG = c(9.56736426869569, 
9.73753926605387, 9.78976436754936, 9.78577886714304, 9.76641272417325, 
9.80119459273923, 9.82375142221191, 10.5747980384869, 10.6791589746007, 
10.6632180372392, 10.5604374447842, 10.4398347135322, 10.261895993101, 
10.0481072421461, 10.8599792861544, 11.0143083465337, 11.0290176185546, 
10.9322494593032, 9.84384369960861, 10.0221146762943, 9.99524597777567, 
8.51171827041292, 8.53803445653107, 8.43611330054631, 8.38027325164503, 
8.3269282159168, 8.38854128098197, 8.5442050446523, 8.89351782318383, 
8.92360453139329, 8.96441423278807, 8.93208043810331, 9.18778796750567, 
9.69109846411978, 9.75086071107721, 12.2523549056307, 12.3587164763448, 
12.4441166319283, 12.4913493273481, 12.4916387308594, 12.4687368650067, 
12.4443254746449, 9.81141616514545, 9.77407912202464, 9.88514535828826, 
9.87646055234287, 9.83315624388896, 9.81630520922804, 9.90160580268615, 
12.7100307417182, 12.7182823110683, 12.7565265916732, 12.7642388118431, 
12.7271198504863, 12.7077989961906, 12.7619414221787, 8.22777628167074, 
8.38341031627978, 8.56316036427592, 8.58307456052975, 8.7524075805257, 
8.72246597631381, 9.12764329007411, 10.072259391783, 10.2186631892968, 
10.2827113494391, 10.3809631966206, 10.5171043941393, 10.2035921449865, 
10.1300253369184, 8.51797111141425, 8.65191374487273, 8.74270627691564, 
8.81312030587554, 8.87514902365156, 8.8293755227843, 8.77028192359486, 
9.24131769131151, 9.2427104683695, 9.21599826167033, 9.13028362611817, 
9.03459301705783, 9.15225152771786, 9.27726550821295, 7.99482826345879, 
8.0862872208779, 8.11124725483796, 8.15898023498527, 8.22186975840737, 
8.29828662307883, 8.43357802939057, 10.2033328521137, 10.3782610379096, 
10.3586313188748, 10.2640947550025, 10.3283303610705, 10.4146631150664, 
10.4312587850283, 10.3536391782667, 10.4718082001492, 10.4806625568437, 
10.4915797263212, 10.3831630085098, 10.3447701535097, 9.99934303817965, 
10.2209953818852, 10.2972174044259, 10.1171462646391, 10.123265446374, 
10.1338847325616, 9.95375281868368, 9.93124862332152, 9.58674389405408, 
9.55761537614691, 9.62926668371527, 9.65604661844032, 9.56454021436101, 
9.63059672022673, 9.67037306957062, 11.0028329057801, 11.0699142407881, 
11.148261551166, 10.937721307268, 10.6790668914495, 10.671487070998, 
10.6460437533536, 9.52490544409675, 9.67125755614516, 9.78174686660155, 
9.63590607411557, 9.64511255667316, 9.68897855199934, 9.73186480878888, 
9.57373270366244, 9.67268978228506, 9.67174463240845, 9.77468780514454, 
9.74542924787785, 9.66580126640559, 9.71341604228211), D.Material = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), D.Energie = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), gut = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), exzellent = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), schlecht = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), befriedigend = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0)), row.names = c("1209-2011", "1209-2012", "1209-2013", 
"1209-2014", "1209-2015", "1209-2016", "1209-2017", "1380-2011", 
"1380-2012", "1380-2013", "1380-2014", "1380-2015", "1380-2016", 
"1380-2017", "1678-2011", "1678-2012", "1678-2013", "1678-2014", 
"1678-2015", "1678-2016", "1678-2017", "1913-2011", "1913-2012", 
"1913-2013", "1913-2014", "1913-2015", "1913-2016", "1913-2017", 
"1988-2011", "1988-2012", "1988-2013", "1988-2014", "1988-2015", 
"1988-2016", "1988-2017", "2991-2011", "2991-2012", "2991-2013", 
"2991-2014", "2991-2015", "2991-2016", "2991-2017", "4213-2011", 
"4213-2012", "4213-2013", "4213-2014", "4213-2015", "4213-2016", 
"4213-2017", "4503-2011", "4503-2012", "4503-2013", "4503-2014", 
"4503-2015", "4503-2016", "4503-2017", "4510-2011", "4510-2012", 
"4510-2013", "4510-2014", "4510-2015", "4510-2016", "4510-2017", 
"5439-2011", "5439-2012", "5439-2013", "5439-2014", "5439-2015", 
"5439-2016", "5439-2017", "5581-2011", "5581-2012", "5581-2013", 
"5581-2014", "5581-2015", "5581-2016", "5581-2017", "5667-2011", 
"5667-2012", "5667-2013", "5667-2014", "5667-2015", "5667-2016", 
"5667-2017", "6078-2011", "6078-2012", "6078-2013", "6078-2014", 
"6078-2015", "6078-2016", "6078-2017", "6104-2011", "6104-2012", 
"6104-2013", "6104-2014", "6104-2015", "6104-2016", "6104-2017", 
"7017-2011", "7017-2012", "7017-2013", "7017-2014", "7017-2015", 
"7017-2016", "7017-2017", "7881-2011", "7881-2012", "7881-2013", 
"7881-2014", "7881-2015", "7881-2016", "7881-2017", "8030-2011", 
"8030-2012", "8030-2013", "8030-2014", "8030-2015", "8030-2016", 
"8030-2017", "8068-2011", "8068-2012", "8068-2013", "8068-2014", 
"8068-2015", "8068-2016", "8068-2017", "8151-2011", "8151-2012", 
"8151-2013", "8151-2014", "8151-2015", "8151-2016", "8151-2017", 
"8247-2011", "8247-2012", "8247-2013", "8247-2014", "8247-2015", 
"8247-2016", "8247-2017"), class = c("pdata.frame", "data.frame"
), index = structure(list(gvkey = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), .Label = c("1209", "1380", 
"1678", "1913", "1988", "2991", "4213", "4503", "4510", "5439", 
"5581", "5667", "6078", "6104", "7017", "7881", "8030", "8068", 
"8151", "8247"), class = "factor"), Year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("2011", "2012", 
"2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
140L), class = c("pindex", "data.frame")))
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you report an example? Also, "testing for VIFs" is, more often than not, actually not needed. Multiple regression exists precisely to handle correlated predictors.

Comment: Yes for sure, I will edit the question.

Comment: Does a `plm` model provide an intercept? From the `vif()`  documentation in the [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car):  "VIFs or GVIFs for linear and similar regression models without intercepts are generally not sensible." Plus, what @ChristophHanck said about whether they are even needed.

Comment: I see that's the problem! Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, `plm` does not, because it estimates individual-specific intercepts (the fixed effects), so that there is no room left for an overall intercept. You could retrieve these with `fixef()`.

Comment: That said, while something in the column space of the intercept is necessary for VIF as it involves an R^2, which could otherwise be negative (that at least is the only reason I see for insisting on an intercept for VIF), the warning does not quite convince me as the fixed effects do indeed amount to just that, i.e., the fixed effects combine into a constant such that R^2 could not be negative.